# how to do code listing in Latex without line numbers (when using lstlisting environment)

Tags: latex

I have been writing a project report and have added some pseudo codes using the following command : lstlisting in Latex as shown bellow.

```
         \begin{lstlisting}[language=c++]

             # On leave focus of email field

           IF email is blank
         Error message: "Please enter an email address"

           ELSE IF email field value is not a valid email address
        Error message: "Wrong email please try again"}  

         # On leave focus of password

          IF password is not sufficiently strong
       Error message: "Password strength is not good" 

         \end{lstlisting}
```

The above works just fine but in the code block thy are some line numbers appearing and I would like to get ride of those. Any hints on how to remove them?
I also know the following:

```
     \section*{New section}
```

Would give a section title without number. But in the case of code listing it doesn't work and produce an error instead.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You used:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=c++]
```

Specifying that the language is C++, the same way you can specify you don't whant line numbers:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=c++,numbers=none]
```

In the code you posted this is not C++ and you said it is for pseudocode, so you can get rid of the language parameter and just keep:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=none]
```

Comment: The space for line numbers will still be reserved. How can you also get rid of that unused space?